# Python Tkinter not opening when using .grid()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am working through online tutorials to learn how to make a GUI with Tkinter. But i am having an issue when using the .grid() function.

Here is what i have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
title = Label(root, text = "Hello World")
title.pack()

name           = Label(root, text = "Name")
password       = Label(root, text = "Password")
entry_name     = Entry(root)
entry_password = Entry(root)

name.grid           (row = 0, sticky = E)
password.grid       (row = 0, sticky = E)
entry_name.grid     (row = 0, column = 1)
entry_password.grid (row = 1, column = 1)

check = Checkbutton(root, text = "Keep me logged in")
check.grid(columnspan = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

So the problem im having is as soon as i include that first line:

```
name.grid(row = 0, sticky = E)
```

And then run the script, there are no errors, but nothing opens. The program just hangs and i have to close the command prompt in order to regain control.

If i comment out all the lines using .grid() they program works fine and will open a window with my title inside it.

So, does anyone know what im doing wrong? 
Im using Python 2.7

Comment: Looks like you're already using `pack()` within `root`. Mixing geometry managers usually produces some kind of error message, but have you tried fixing that?

Comment: You cannot use pack and grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use both `pack` and `grid` with two or more widgets that share the same parent. In your case you're using `pack` for `title` and `grid` for everything else. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

Keep grid geometry manager consistent so use title.grid().

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
title = Label(root, text = "Hello World")
title.grid()

name           = Label(root, text = "Name")
password       = Label(root, text = "Password")
entry_name     = Entry(root)
entry_password = Entry(root)

name.grid(row = 0, sticky = E)
password.grid       (row = 0, sticky = E)
entry_name.grid     (row = 0, column = 1)
entry_password.grid (row = 1, column = 1)

check = Checkbutton(root, text = "Keep me logged in")
check.grid(columnspan = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Beginners mistake.

Comment: No worries - been there!